# How can I add optional named parameters to a TypeScript function parameter?

Tags: typescript

I'd like to be able to define a method that accepts an arrow function as a parameter. The function parameter should be able to define 0 or more named parameters of its own. How can I do this?

I've tried

```
public doSomething(fn: () => any) {}
```

and

```
public doSomething(fn: (...args) => any) {}
```

but they both throw a "supplied parameters do not match" error when I try to call it as follows:

```
doSomething((test: string) => {})
```

(*Note that the type and number of parameters to this function may vary on each usage, so I can't set the type(s) on the original method.*)

I can supply parameters using the `...args` syntax within the passed function, but I would like to be able to type and name specific parameters.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two options. Reasons *Type Safety*. If you work through the statements below it should be clear.

## Fix the callback:

If your function expects to call the callback with 0 or more arguments, then the callback must be okay with it (i.e. have optional arguments) i.e.

```
function doSomething(fn: () => any) {}

// All arguments need to optional 
doSomething((a?:string)=>{});
```

Same as :

```
function doSomething(fn: (...args:string[]) => any) {}

// All arguments need to optional 
doSomething((a?:string)=>{});
```

## Fix the callback signature:

If you are going to call the callback with exactly 'N' arguments, specify their names in the signature. It is up to the callback to *take* or *ignore* these. Eg. this callback ignores them:

```
// Specify the number of arguments
function doSomething(fn: (ar1:string,arg2:string) => any) {}

doSomething(()=>{});
```