# TypeScript - Named arguments?

Tags: typescript

In **C#**, it is possible to invoke a given method with named arguments:

`myObject.SetSize(width: 100, height: 100);`

They primarily seem to exist for catering to optional parameters, but... They also drastically improve readability of method call sites. It also protects you from incorrect parameter specification.

From what I have been able to gather, if I wish to benefit from 'declarative call sites' in **TypeScript** I'm best off using 'argument objects' based on a given interface.

```
interface SizeArguments {
  width: number;
  height: number;
}

export class MyClass {

  setSize(args: SizeArguments) {
    /* Set size... */
  }
}

new MyClass().setSize({ width: 100, height: 100 });
```

Works for me! But that's still quite a lot of work for something so trivial in C#. Is this approach the best I can do right now? Or am I overseeing something fundamentally?

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/467 for the reasons to not add it to TypeScript.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108807/using-named-parameters-javascriptbased-on-typescript/42108988#42108988

Comment: Instead of going through the pain of creating "argument objects" for every function, just declare them inline: `setSize(args: { width: number, height: number })`

Comment: That looks cool @IanKemp; I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @IanKemp that's an excellent suggestion - you should post it as an answer ('no, but try this...').

Comment: in Ocaml its called "labeled" arguments. will TS ever get such a feature?