# In VSCode extension, how to open a terminal with cmd.exe?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

My extension opens a terminal to run a specific command.

Openning the terminal is not a problem, however, specifying the terminal path is.

I am working on Windows, but my default terminal is git bash. As a consequence, results of `path.join`, which contain single backslashes (windows...), used in the command, does not work with git bash.

I want to make sure the windows cmd.exe terminal is used to avoid this problem (all users are on windows, this is not problematic).

The [documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#window) says that we can specify a terminal path. I tried to provide the path of cmd.exe obtained from `process.env.COMSPEC`, without success:

```
console.log(process.env.COMSPEC)
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal(
    name = "Create Projet", shellPath = process.env.COMSPEC)
```

Throws:

> C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
>
> ReferenceError: shellPath
> is not defined    at
> c:\Users\user\Documents\template-python-cli\vscode\project\out\extension.js:58:55
> at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
> at async l._executeContributedCommand
> (c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS
> Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\services\extensions\node\extensionHostProcess.js:94:111644)

But as the log above says, the value exists.

How can I tell the extension to open `cmd.exe` with `createTerminal` ?

Comment: @rioV8 Why removing the extension tag ? This occurs in an extension program.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, unfortunately too used to the way named parameters work in Python.
Anyway, solution is:

```
const terminal = vscode.window.createTerminal("Create Projet",
                    process.env.COMSPEC)
```

This is kind of a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/42108988/6213883