# TS Lint rule to disallow multiple paramters of the same type

Tags: typescript, lint, tslint, typescript-eslint

Is there any sort of linter that supports a rule that would disallow the following:

```
function testFn(a: string, b: string)
```

but would allow:

```
function testFn(a: number, b: string)
```

I've seen that eslint can set max params, but it's a max params of a *certain type* that I wish to disallow.

The reason is that it's easy to mix the params up and pass them in the same order. With typescript it will let me know if my params are backwards as the types don't match, but I wouldn't know with strings.
In the case that I wish to pass two I would prefer to restructure them, so:

```
function testFn(params: { a: string, b: string })
```

Comment: why not use a parameter object instead? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42108807/using-named-parameters-in-javascript-based-on-typescript

Comment: @Dai I think that's what he wants. A linter rule rule which enforces refractoring to a parameter object in such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such rule right now. This rule request is a pretty specific feature request so it's not likely to be built into typescript-eslint core anytime soon. You can always create one yourself with the tooling at https://typescript-eslint.io/developers/custom-rules, then publish it as your own standalone ESLint plugin.

By the way, just for visibility: "tslint" / "ts-lint" refers to the old deprecated [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint) project. TSLint was deprecated a few years back in favor of [typescript-eslint](https://typescript-eslint.io), which is tooling that lets you run ESLint (and other common JS libraries) on TypeScript code.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you for the info. Just wanted to check before I went and built my own.